# In Redux Toolkit, can I call a reducer function defined in a slice from an extraReducer function in a different slice?

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-toolkit

Basically I have to change the status of one slice as per results of an async thunk defined for a different slice. If that is not possible, which would be the recommended approach?

As per ChatGPT recommendation, I tried calling

```js
action.payload.dispatch(increment());
```

where increment is a reducer from slice "A"

sliceA.js

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const sliceA = createSlice({
  name: 'sliceA',
  initialState: {
    countA: 0,
  },
  reducers: {
    increment: (state) => {
      state.countA += 1;
    },
  },
});

export const { increment } = sliceA.actions;
export default sliceA.reducer;
```

then in slice "B" I try to call A's increment reducer

sliceB.js

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { increment } from './sliceA'; // Import the "increment" action from sliceA

const sliceB = createSlice({
  name: 'sliceB',
  initialState: {
    countB: 0,
  },
  reducers: {
    someReducerInSliceB: (state, action) => {
      // Your reducer logic for sliceB
    },
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase('exampleAction', (state, action) => {
      // Dispatch the "increment" action from sliceA
      action.payload.dispatch(increment()); // This will update the countA in sliceA
    });
  },
});

export const { someReducerInSliceB } = sliceB.actions;
export default sliceB.reducer;
```

It causes a runtime error: "action.payload.dispatch is not a function".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reducer functions don't have direct action to the ThunkAPI or `dispatch` function. Reducers are pure functions, so they shouldn't have side-effects like dispatching actions. You also are not calling reducer functions, directly, but rather are dispatching actions to the store and the store is calling the root reducer function and passing the current state object and action to it, propagating down the reducer tree to compute the next state value.

If I understand your question correctly you want some state in both slice A and in slice B to update when a "exampleAction" action is dispatched. Slice A can also declare an extra reducer case to handle the same action and apply its own logic.

Example:

```js
const sliceA = createSlice({
  name: 'sliceA',
  initialState: {
    countA: 0,
  },
  reducers: {
    increment: (state) => {
      state.countA += 1;
    },
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase('exampleAction', (state, action) => {
      state.countA += 1;
    });
  },
});
```

If you want to make the code more ***DRY*** then you can abstract the reducer function into a single function.

```js
const increment = (state, action) => {
  state.countA += 1;
};

const sliceA = createSlice({
  name: 'sliceA',
  initialState: {
    countA: 0,
  },
  reducers: {
    increment,
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase('exampleAction', increment);
  },
});
```

Comment: what I infer from your answer is that an extraReducer from any slice can "catch" the promise returned from any asyncThunk created function. The state passed into the extraReducer "catcher" is the sliced state defined by the slice. Is it right? I tried that in my code and it looks like it works. I used to think that the asyncThunk created functions were tied to a slice but no: they are independent... Sounds great!

Comment: @Sammybar One of the base Redux concepts is that reducer functions can "react" and handle ***any*** action that is dispatched to the store. If you recall the old way of doing things you'd write a reducer function and use a `switch(action.type)` block to define what you wanted the reducer to do for specific actions. RTK slice reducers abstract this a bit, but in the `extraReducers` you effectively define how to handle external (*to the slice*) actions. Actions are just that, actions, and are not coupled to any specific state slice. Yes, the `state` is for a specific state slice/reducer.